# Access first li in list without recursivity

Tags: html, css, html-lists

I have this structure:

```
<div id="sidebar">
<ul>
<li>
    <a href="a.link/">"Main item"</a>
    <ul>
        <li class="cat-item cat-item-21">
            <a href="a.link/">"Child item"</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

It's generated and I cannot modify it. But, using CSS, I want to make the "Main Item" unclickable, using:

```
pointer-events:none
```

How can I acces the first "li" in the "ul" and modifiy his CSS without touch the rest ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the `>` identifier to only specify to go one level deep per element you're looking at such as...

```
#sidebar > ul > li > a{ pointer-events:none }
```

This will select only the first a of the first li of the first ul inside #sidebar